# Send windows 10 to hibernate instead of sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

On my desktop computer I have a glitch that when the computer goes to sleep and then wakes up, the videocard produces artifacts (very slow update to changes, so you see heavy tearing in videogames or fast videos)

Since it works quite well otherwise my wish would be to disable sleep and **only use hibernation**
Is that achievable?

Additional info:

- windows 10 version: 2004 (19041.264)
- I don't have an "hybrid sleep" option in my Windows Power Options

Comment: In Advanced Power Options, set Sleep to Never and then enable Hibernate to an interval.

Comment: why comment when giving an answer? this was better than the proposed answer!
THANKS

Comment: Did my suggested answer above help

Comment: it did. I thought pc went to sleep and then AFTER it went to hibernate. Not that those options were indipendent from each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Advanced Power Options and set Sleep to Never. 
Then enable Hibernate to an interval that works for you or hibernate from the Start button on demand.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, editing the GUI didn't work for me. I ran powercfg.exe -query and I saw this:

```
    Power Setting GUID: 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364  (Hibernate after)
      GUID Alias: HIBERNATEIDLE
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
```

The 0x0....0 at the end usually means it's disabled, even tho I had enabled it in the GUI.

So I edited it at the command-line in Powershell:

```
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-dc 30
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-ac 60
```

Afterwards, it worked properly and hibernated. Make sure you also set your Sleep to Never.

When testing, I recommend using much shorter numbers than 30 and 60.

Footnote: my motivation for going straight to hibernate instead of hybrid sleep is that when you enable Hyper-V for WSL2, it disables Hybrid Sleep (see https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9695#issuecomment-1705855022).

Answer (score 0):

Go to power options in Control Panel, change when the computer sleeps and set to never.